# How to create a multiple radio group in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

How to create a multiple radio where there's a question and you will just choose `Passed` or `Failed`. it will not affect the other item when you choosing the `passed` or `failed`

for example:

Item 1 - What do you think? you will pass or fail? : *Passed   * Failed

Item 2 - Your classmate anna will be pass or fail? : *Passed   * Failed

Item 3 - Your best friend grade will be pass or fail? : *Passed   * Failed

Answer (score 0):

Created a example for your functionality

[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-input-radio-5xahaz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 0):

> Item.ts file

```
class Item{
  id : number;
  question : string;
  isPassed : boolean;
}
```

> app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent  {
items : Item[]=[];

 constructor(){
    console.log("onitnit")
    this.items.push({
      'id':1,
      'question': 'question1?',
      'isPassed':false,
    })
    this.items.push({
      'id':2,
      'question': 'question2?',
      'isPassed':false,
    })
    this.items.push({
      'id':3,
      'question': 'question3?',
      'isPassed':false,
    })
  }

  resultHandler(){
    console.log(this.items);
  }
}
```

> app.component.html file

```
        <div *ngFor = "let item of items" style="display : flex;">
           {{item.question}} 
           <form style="margin-left:20px">
              passed: <input type="radio" name="orders" [value]="item.id"/>
             failed: <input type="radio" name="orders" [value]="item.id"/>
           </form>
        </div>
```

[working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vv82x2)

See console for final result generated.

Answer (score 0):

You can set name attribute unique for each group. Let say -

```
<input type="radio" name="{{index}}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Multiple radio group with reactive form.

HTML:

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <div *ngFor="let que of questions">
    <span>{{que.question}}</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <mat-radio-group [formControlName]="que.id" aria-label="Select an option">
      <mat-radio-button value="true">Passed</mat-radio-button>
      <mat-radio-button value="false">Failed</mat-radio-button>
    </mat-radio-group>
  </div>
  <pre>{{form.value | json}}</pre>
</form>
```

TS:

```
form: FormGroup;

  questions = [{
    id: "1",
    question: "What do you think? you will pass or fail?",
    result: false
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    question: "Your classmate anna will be pass or fail?",
    result: false
  },
  {
    id: '3', 
    question: "Your best friend grade will be pass or fail?",
    result: false
  }]

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = this.fb.group({ });
      this.questions.forEach(question => {
      this.form.addControl(question.id, this.fb.control(null, Validators.required));
      })
  }
```

stackblitz link : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pyfprq

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why all the example I come across are complex.

Here is how radio buttons can be used in an Angular Reactive form in a basic state.

```
form = <FormGroup>this.formBuilder.group({
  type: this.formBuilder.control({ value: null, disabled: false}
});
```

HTML view

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" [formGroup]="form" [ngClass]="{'student': form.value.student}">
  <input type="radio" value="student" formControlName="type" id='student' name='type' />
  <input type="radio" value="professional" formControlName="type" id='professional' name='type' />
  <input type="radio" value="executive" formControlName="type" id='executive' name='type' />

  <button type="submit">
    Get started
  </button>
</form>
```